# Move your Working Copy

Tags: linux, svn

I tried to find out how to move my working copy.  I know SVN move can be used to move files and folders inside your working copy but what about the working copy itself?  I want to move it because I created a branch in a folder location that's different from my branch and had updated therefore all my .NET project references.  So when I go to merge back to the mainline trunk I get a bunch of tree conflicts.

I'm runing linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual working copy directory may be moved at will using your client operating system commands (i.e. Windows Explorer if you're using tortoisSVN).  The working copy contains all the meta-data needed to remain consistent with the original repository from which you checked out the local working copy.